# PHPMailer bot sending e-mails?

Tags: php, html

So apparently one of my associates came with that weird e-mail he received from a bot... We both coded to use PHPMailer to control a certain area of our company and receive submissions from people interested in our service, having in the body of the e-mail Name, E-mail, Number, and a message.

Here is what shows in the e-mail:

[image: Weird e-mail oO]

And here is some coding:

```
    $mail->AddAddress('ouvidoria@fsg.br');
    $mail->Subject = 'Ouvidoria FSG: '. $entity->getTipoAsString() .' '. $entity->getAssunto()->getDescricao();

    $mail->Body = sprintf('<b>Nova solicitação de: </b> %s <br/><b>Telefones: </b>%s %s<br/><b>E-mail: </b>%s <br/><b>Envolvidos: </b>%s<br /><b>Descrição: </b>%s<br />',
        $entity->getNome(),
        $entity->getTelefone1(),
        $entity->getTelefone2(),
        $entity->getEmail(),
        $entity->getEnvolvidos(),
        $entity->getDescricao()
    );

    $mail->Send();
```

All gets are part of the Entity code, don't see anything different than before in this code.

Anyone know what could it be?

EDIT 1: To clarify the question, **this e-mail should not exist, I need to find a way to stop this bot emails**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? It's a simple bot using your form?

Comment: This email shouldn't exist, don't know if this clarify something. But we need to prevent this kind of e-mails this bot is generating.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, if a bot is using your form to submit random email spam, you can either add some sort of captcha or you may just verify if the sender's email actually exists or is allowed to use your form.

Comment: @briosheje yes, I need something sort of a captcha to catch this bots and prevent this kind of e-mail

Comment: Then add a captcha, there's plenty out there, you're not the first with this issue, google it.